# Find an expression for the variance of the upper quantile of the Gumbel Distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, variance

> Show that the $p$th **upper** (right tail) quantile of the Gumbel Distribution is given by, $z_p$:
>
> $$z_p = \mu - \beta \log\{-\log(1-p)\}$$
>
> Find MLEs of the 10 year return level and the 100 year return level. Find an expression for var$(z_p)$ to find an approximate 95% Confidence Interval for the $10$ year return level and the $100$ year return level.
>
> (The $10$ and $100$ year return level have a value for $p$ of $0.1$ and $0.01$ respectively, it's a dataset based on rainfall. )

---

So for this, I have set the distribution function (for a Gumbel Distribution), $F(y;\mu,\beta)$, equal to $1-p$:

$$F(y;\mu,\beta)=\exp[-\exp\{- \frac{y-\mu} \beta \}]$$
$$1-p=\exp[-\exp\{- \dfrac{y-\mu}{\beta} \}]$$

Solve for $y$ and you get the required function, $z_p$. This part is fine.

---

If you run a `gumbelFit`in R (for the dataset we've been given) you get estimates for $\hat{\mu} = 3.869$ and $\hat{\beta} = 0.195$, which means I caclulated the $MLE_{10} = 4.1302$ and $MLE_{100}=4.3292$. This part is also fine.

---

Finding the expression for var$(z_p)$ is what I find difficult. I have the formula, I think:

$$\operatorname{var}\{z_p\} \approx \left(\frac{\partial z_p}{\partial \mu}, \frac{\partial z_p}{\partial \beta}\right) \hat{J}^{-1} \left(\frac{\partial z_p}{\partial \mu}, \dfrac{\partial z_p}{\partial \beta}\right)^T$$

What I dont know about this is what to use for $\hat{J}^{-1}$. It's an inverse matrix, yes, but with what elements?

---

Then how would I use $z_p$ to find a confidence interval? Perhaps it is something like this:

$$z_p \pm \operatorname{SE}(z_p)$$ where the standard error is $\sqrt{\operatorname{var}(z_p)}$.

I appreciate any insight into this.

Comment: When you write \text{exp} instead of \exp then you see $3\text{exp}5$ instead of $3\exp5.$ That the spacing depends on context with \exp can be seen by contrasting $3\exp5 $ and $3\exp(5). \qquad$